# Save image in any weight and immediately reduce it

Tags: media

I am building a site using drupal 7. I created a node form for users to write content and upload images (using the core image field).

Is it possible to let users to upload images of 5-10 MB (and more), and immediately reduce the weight of the image to only 1 MB, and only then save it on my Drupal site?

My goal is that user will be able to upload any image size they want, but still save space on my Drupal site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding that drupal 7 does that out of the box (although it's possible I have a module doing it.  Rather than fixing the size of the file, set the max pixels for the image and drupal will resize it (and thus reduce the size) on upload.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I will set the "Maximum image resolution" - it will shrink the image on the client side?

Comment: On the server side, but yeah.  And visitors will see the resized photo.